# What do they mean by mastering algebra?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, self-learning

So everyone is saying "to tackle diff. and int. calc you have to master algebra first".

Now, I'm self-studying and I have no idea what "mastering algebra" means in that sense. Functions? Quadratics? Polynomials? Factorization? Complex Numbers? Logarithms? Expo. growth? Advanced functions? All of the above?

What are your opinions for pre-requisite level algebraic knowledge?

Comment: I'd say it means knowing that $\left(x + y\right)^n \ne x^n + y^n$ in general.

Comment: Thanks Decaf, that what freakin beautiful.

Comment: All of the above, please.

Comment: It means that you should breath algebra as your mother tongue. You should dream algebrq at night

Comment: That sounds pretty serious, gotta get to it then I guess.

Comment: Ideally, you should be comfortable with the material presented in a standard precalculus book. Precalculus texts usually have no actual calculus (if they do it's maybe one chapter in the end introducing limits). They are designed to teach you what you should know before doing calculus.

Comment: Grenard, at Khan Academy Pre-Calc section is about 5% of the math covered in Alg 1 and 2. I doubt that skipping Algebra 1 and 2 and doing pre calc is enough..

Comment: It means that you have to be fairly proficient in manipulations and problem-solving that involve trigonometric functions, polynomials (and friends like $x^{5/9}=\sqrt[9]{x^5}$), logarithms, exponentials and absolute value. Complex numbers will be useful eventually, but they might not be from the start. In other words, it means being an accomplished student of high-school "precalculus".

Comment: For example, can you simplify $\frac{(x+h)^3 - x^3}{h}$ ?  (And did it seem easy?) By the way, if you begin learning calculus and discover some gaps in your knowledge of algebra, you can always go back to basics and fill in the gaps.

Comment: Well I'm not familiar with what is covered at Khan Academy, so I can't say if it's comparable to a precalculus textbook. But again, the precalc books I have taught from have been pretty algebra heavy, and if you are really comfortable with all that shows up there, you should be good on the algebra side of things.

Comment: This roughly means that you should be good at algebraic manipulation including the use of trigonometric identities. It does mean that you can solve quadratic equations, but in general you don't need to be a master of algebra (a typical master of algebra is one who can solve $x^{17}-1=0$ and get the value of $\cos(2\pi/17)$ in explicit form using radicals). Exponential and logarithmic functions are developed using calculus and it is intellectually dishonest to expect someone to have a knowledge of these functions via algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculus, at its most basic level, requires only a few concepts, most importantly **functions**. You should also know high-school algebra, things like $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and similar should be engraved in your memory.
Exponentials and logarithms are one of the fundamental functions of basic calculus, it is thus very important to grasp these concepts.
Complex numbers, although very elegant, and I personally recommend learning them, are not needed for basic calculus. More elaborate topics make plenty of uses of complex numbers, but it is not so hard to learn the most important facts.
If you want some recommendations on where to start learning, the calculus video series on YóuTube by 3Blue1Brown is a *very* nice intro, and if you prefer a book, *The Calculus Lifesaver* by Princeton University Press is also very good.